# Best to use SQL + JOINS or Stored Proc to combine results from multiple queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating a table to summarize data that is gathered from about 8 or so queries that have very light logic/WHERE clauses and all select against different tables.

I was wondering what the best option would be to fetch the summarized data:

- One query with multiple JOINS to gather all relevant information
- A stored proc that encapsulates the logic and maybe executes the 8 queries and does the "joining" in some other way?  This seems more modular and maintainable to me...but I'm not sure.

I am using SQL Server 2008 for this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, then use usual SQL methods. Db's are optimized to run them. This "joining in some other way" would probably require the use of cursor which slows down everything. Just let the db do its job. If you need more performance then you should examine execution plan and do what has to be done there(eg. adding indexes).

Answer (score 1):

Databases are pretty good at figuring out the optimal way of executing SQL. It is what they are designed to do. Using stored procedures to load the data in chunks and combining it yourself will be more complex to write, and likely to be less efficient than letting the database just do it for you.

If you are concerned about reusing a complex query in multiple places, consider creating a view of it instead.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the tables, joining 8 of them could be pretty hairy. I would try it that way first - as others have said, the db is pretty good at figuring this stuff out. If the performance is not as good as you would like, I would try a stored proc which creates a table variable (or a temp table) and inserts the data from each of the 8 tables separately. Then you can return the contents of the table variable to your app.

This method also makes it a little easier to add the 9th, 10th, etc tables in the future. And it gives you an easy way to do any processing you may need on the summarized data before returning it to your app.

Comment: This is true indeed, but first thing which has to be done is making sure that the queries that are running are optimal - you have indexes where needed, no full scan is performed etc. This is probably not easy for inexperienced user, but a lot of resources are available on msdn.

Comment: Thanks all.  It also doesn't help that I have no control over this database, I'm just trying to turn a "get the queries as text files manually and do a mainframe job" process into something more automated and "modern"...